# Eliminate selected rows in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to delete a row of my data table based on the values of two columns, but with no luck.

I tried two codes that I found in other threads:

```
my.data.table[!(my.data.table[,1]==6557 & my.data.table[,2]=="31-Dec-82"),] 
  ###var1 is in column 1 and var2 is in column 2

my.data.table %>% filter(var1!= 6557 & var2!="31-Dec-82")
```

but none works. Note that `var1` is numeric and `var2` is character (not date for now).
The only approach I could make work is by looking up the row number manually

```
my.data.table<-my.data.table[-rownumber]
```

but this is not very convenient in a 1M row table, even if sorted.

Any idea why I cannot make it work?

Comment: You're terminology is confusing.  Do you have a dataframe or a data.table?  If the latter, you have to subset differently than with base R:`my.data.table <- my.data.table[var1 != 6557]`

Comment: `DT[!.(6557, "31-Dec-82"), on=names(DT)[1:2]]` is the data.table syntax for an anti join. Or `df %>% anti_join(data_frame(var1 = 6557, var2 = "31-Dec-82"))` if going the dplyr route from data like @MauritsEvers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `data.table`,

```
my.data.table[,1]
```

won't subset the column as it in `data.frame`.  The column values can be extracted as a `vector` with `[[`

```
my.data.table[[1]]
```

i.e.

```
my.data.table[!(my.data.table[[1]]==6557 & my.data.table[[2]] =="31-Dec-82"),]
```

---

Or specify the names of the column

```
my.data.table[!(var1==6557 & var2 =="31-Dec-82")]
```

---

Another option to subset the data.table columns would be specify `with = FALSE`

```
my.data.table[, 1, with = FALSE]
```

but this will return a single column `data.table` instead of a `vector`

Comment: Thank you, this works. Sometimes I still get confused as to what I can do with a data frame and a data table (obv I'm new to R)

Answer (score 1):

Provided I understood you correctly, you want to remove rows where *both* `var1 == 6447` *and* `var2 == "31-Dec-82"`. This corresponds to negating the logical expression `var1 == 6557 & var2 == "31-Dec-82"`.

### Method using `dplyr::filter`

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
    var1 = 6556:6558,
    var2 = c("31-Dec-82", "31-Dec-82", "30-Dec-82")
)

df %>% filter(!(var1 == 6557 & var2 == "31-Dec-82"))
#  var1      var2
#1 6556 31-Dec-82
#2 6558 30-Dec-82
```

### Method using base R's `subset`

```
subset(df, !(var1 == 6557 & var2 == "31-Dec-82"))
#  var1      var2
#1 6556 31-Dec-82
#3 6558 30-Dec-82
```